# GDAL python : How to convert GEOTIFF to TIFF

Tags: python, tiff, gdal, geotiff

I would like to convert a GEOTIFF to a normal TIFF with python. I'm trying to use gdal but cannot if more than one page..

How can I do it please ?

Thanks for help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `gdal.Translate` for this. [more info](https://gdal.org/programs/gdal_translate.html)

snippet:

```
from osgeo import gdal
    
options_list = [
    '-ot Byte',
    '-of JPEG',
    '-b 1',
    '-scale'
]           

options_string = " ".join(options_list)
    
gdal.Translate(
    'save_image_path.jpg',
    'image_path.tif',
    options=options_string
)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer ! It works good but I need to save the converted image in "TIFF" format. And when I replace "JPEG" by "TIFF" I got the error "Output driver `TIFF' not recognised"